# Storybook passing args to arrow function

Tags: reactjs, storybook

I am trying to pass args to MyComponent as below from a SB story.

```
export default {
  title: "Storybook",
  component: MyComponent,
  // More on argTypes: https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/api/argtypes
}; 
const Template = ({ args }) => {
  return (
      <MyComponent {...args} />
  );
};

export const First = Template.bind({});
// More on args: https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/writing-stories/args
First.args = {
  storyName: "First One",
  prop1: "One - 1",
  prop2: "Two - 2",
};
```

Component defined like below.

```
export const MyComponent = ({ prop1, prop2 }) => { 
  return (
    <span>{prop1}--{prop1}</span>
  );
};
```

prop1 & prop2 are are undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const Template = ({ args }) => {
  return (
      <MyComponent {...args} />
  );
};
```

The above template should be like below

```
const Template = (args) => {
  return (
      <MyComponent {...args} />
  );
};
```

[Storybook Args](https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/writing-stories/args)

Comment: it worked..thanks a lot...
Silly mistake..